# How can I send data with Ajax to the specified user without request from the specified user

Tags: php, ajax

Consider a user does the login operation successfully.Now I have a session from the specified user and it is as follows:

`$_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;`

I searched about this issue in internet and I understood that I should use the `Ajax`. I saw this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/what_is_xmlhttprequest.htm) but I could not understand that which method should I use to send the data to the specified user.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Which data you wanna sent to specific user ?

Comment: The user that is logged and the data is a simple text and after that the user pays from my site. I should send a simple text to him.

Comment: you have to be more clear, you wana send a text or want to show a text, there is a huge difference here.

Comment: I want show a text on the computer or on the mobile that the user uses from them.

Answer (score 0):

The **$_SESSION** variable is globally available so you can just use it in the file that renders the page where you want to display the message. 
A request over Ajax is only necessary if you want to avoid a page reload after the user has logged in.

As an example in your view.php:

```
echo 'Welcome back'.$_SESSION['login_user'].'!';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send data (from the server) back to the client by echoing it.
For example you might want to get the dateime from the server to prevent the client tampering with it:

**Server** (assume will return json)

```
$datetime = new Datetime();

$res = array(
    'date' => $datetime->format('d-m-Y'),
    'hour' => $datetime->format('H'),
    'minutes' => $datetime->format('i'),
    'seconds' => $datetime->format('s'),
);

echo json_encode($res);
```

**Client** (assume will use jquery)

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'url_to_the_above_file.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { // dummy post data that can be read server-side
                action : 'some value',
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend : function() {
                //some action BEFORE send here
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                //here is your response from the server
                console.log(date);
                console.log(hour);
                console.log(minutes);
                console.log(seconds);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log("we are in error");
                console.log(data);
            },
            complete: function() {
                //some action AFTER send here
            }
        });
```